# unity plugin for android (failed to receive dispatch signal error in logcat)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

i m trying to make a unity plugin for android. The plugin will show the native android dialog box when clicked on a button in unity. But when i click the button an error arises in the catlog and nuthing happen on device.

The Jar file is made from Eclipse IDE.
Android Jar File contains this function in class:

```
public void OpenDialog()

{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UnityPlayer.currentActivity);

    builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }

           });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }

           });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();

}
```

and i want am trying to call this function from unity C# Script:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 200, 100, 100), "Call Add Method"))
    {
        AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.werplay.unityplugin.AndroidPlugin");
        jo.Call("OpenDialog");
    }

}
```

and this error is coming in catlog of eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to run it inside uı thread,

```
public void OpenDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    UnityPlayer.currentActivity);
            builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }

                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }

                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
}
```